# Get rid off extra output in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am currently learning swift, so I'm working in the swift playground with xcode.

I am working with classes but I get some extra output that it's just kind of distracting for me.

[image]

I don't know if I have modify xcode preference or there is something wrong with my code.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class Person {

    var name = ""

}

class BlogPost {
    var title:String?
    var body = ""
    var author:Person!
    var numberOfComments = 0
}

let post = BlogPost()
if let actualTitle = post.title {

}
```

I just want to get rid off the **__lldb_expr_114.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a protocol oriented approach:

```
import Foundation 
import Swift

protocol PlaygroundFriendlyClass: CustomStringConvertible
{

}

extension PlaygroundFriendlyClass
{
    var description: String
    {
        return String(describing: type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }
}

class Foo: PlaygroundFriendlyClass
{
    init()
    {

    }
}

class Bar: PlaygroundFriendlyClass
{
    init()
    {

    }
}

Foo() // "Foo"
Bar() // "Bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `description` property:

```
var description : String {
   return "BlogPost \(author) - \(title)"
}
```

Comment: Or if you really want to get rid of it (for the sake of testing, of course): `var description : String { return "" }`. It's better to use the `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, or `CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable` protocols for this, though.